# SQL : Get Column table twice with differents clause where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I try to get the same column in the same table twice with different clauses :

My query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 10 
         CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) AS Date, 
         Max(currentcount) AS A 
     FROM   
         logintracking 
     INNER JOIN 
         maxuser ON logintracking.loginid = maxuser.loginid 
     INNER JOIN 
         site ON site.siteid = maxuser.defsite 
     WHERE  
         attemptdate BETWEEN @dateDebut AND @dateFin 
         AND logintracking.clientaddr IN ('10.118.254.21', '10.118.254.156') 
     GROUP BY 
         CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) 
     ORDER BY 
         CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) ASC
    ) AS T1, 
    (SELECT TOP 10 
         CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) AS Date, 
         MAX(currentcount) AS B 
     FROM   
         logintracking 
     INNER JOIN 
         maxuser ON logintracking.loginid = maxuser.loginid 
     INNER JOIN 
         site ON site.siteid = maxuser.defsite 
     WHERE  
         attemptdate BETWEEN @dateDebut AND @dateFin 
         AND logintracking.clientaddr = '10.118.254.35' 
     GROUP BY 
         CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) 
     ORDER BY 
         CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) ASC) AS T2
```

Result:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

My objective is to get the same column 'max(currentcount)' twice and to apply different where clauses so to get two columns named (A & B), and i need also to show the date in the first column, can you please help ? Thanks

Comment: MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Do you want this `max(currentcount) as A, max(currentcount) as B` or this `max(case when foo=bar then currentcount end) as A, max(case when bar=foo then currentcount end) as B`?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a self-join - this link has an example if you scroll down a bit: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp

Comment: i want the second choice, something like max(currentcount) as a when ... and max(currentcount) as b when ...

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: No, my guess is that you need something like "first in a group". Could you please replace your pictures with sample data and a correct result for those data (a minimal example).

Comment: Explain the logic for your desire result. We cant read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only difference between `A` and `B` is `logintracking.clientaddr`, you can put that condition within a `CASE` statement within the `MAX` function:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) AS Date, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN logintracking.clientaddr IN ( '10.118.254.21', '10.118.254.156' ) THEN currentcount END) AS A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN logintracking.clientaddr IN ( '10.118.254.35' ) THEN currentcount END) AS B
FROM logintracking 
    INNER JOIN maxuser 
        ON logintracking.loginid = maxuser.loginid 
    INNER JOIN site 
        ON site.siteid = maxuser.defsite 
WHERE attemptdate BETWEEN @dateDebut AND @dateFin
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) 
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, attemptdate) ASC
```